# Check logical volume mount point (command line)

Tags: linux, command-line, mount, lvm

With GNOME Disks utility, I can check whether a logical volume is mounted:

[image]

And where is it mounted:

[image]

How can I get this information from the command line? Having, for example, the logical volume UUID, I would like to know if it is mounted and where.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `lsblk`. It prints all disks and their corresponding mount points. Including LVM, MD RAID, etc.

Comment: I would mention the `-o MOUNTPOINT` option if you are only interested in getting the mount point (that was the question). And the `-n` option to avoid printing the column names.

Answer (score 5):

You may use this tool:

```
findmnt
```

To find all mount points or pipe it through `grep`, if you know device name, e.g.:

```
findmnt | grep hdd_vg
```

To find a specific UUID, just use:

```
findmnt -rn -S UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -o TARGET
```

To use this simple method, one needs to know the UUID of the partition.

Therefore the step by step guide would be:

```
ls -l /dev/mapper/
```

Then looking up its partition UUID with:

```
blkid /dev/dm-0
```

And finally just look up the mount point:

```
findmnt -rn -S UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -o TARGET
```

Example outputs:

```
ls -l /dev/mapper/
```

gives me:

```
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Nov 13 05:15 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Nov 13 05:18 mint--vg-root -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Nov 13 05:18 mint--vg-swap_1 -> ../dm-1
```

then:

```
blkid /dev/dm-0
```

gives me:

```
/dev/dm-0: UUID="32ee47f8-02df-481d-b731-6e67734999ca" TYPE="ext4"
```

and finally:

```
findmnt -rn -S UUID=32ee47f8-02df-481d-b731-6e67734999ca -o TARGET
```

gives me:

```
/
```

Which is the actual mount point in this VM.

Comment: Now I get it. What you propose is using the *partition* UUID. I was asking for the *logical volume UUID* in my question (the one you see with `lvdisplay`). I guess your solution is valid as well.

Answer (score 3):

Having the UUID of a logical volume, find out whether it's mounted and where.

1. Find out volume group name and logical volume name:

`sudo lvs -o vg_name,name,uuid`

This will list all known logical volumes, with their UUIDs, names and the names of the volume group containing them. Remember the ‹vgname› and ‹lvname› corresponding to the given UUID.

2. Now list all mounted device-backed file systems, and find your logical volume:

`findmnt -l | grep ' /dev/\S\+'`

Simple script:

```
UUID='B3629a-B11c-4aec-bE1f-rUdk-a6d2-dd0a6bc'
LVName="$(
  sudo lvs -o vg_name,name,uuid |
  grep "$UUID" |
  sed -e 's/^\s*\(\S\+\)\s\+\(\S\+\).*/\1-\2/'
)"
if [ -z "$LVName" ] ; then
  echo "Cannot find logical volume with UUID=$UUID"
else
  MountPoint="$(
    findmnt -l |
    grep " /dev/mapper/$LVName" |
    awk '{ print $1 }'
  )"
  if [ -z "$MountPoint" ] ; then
    echo "Logical volume /dev/mapper/$LVName with UUID $UUID is not mounted"
  else
    echo "Logical volume /dev/mapper/$LVName with UUID $UUID is mounted on $MountPoint"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. It works very well. I will wait 24 hours before accepting, in case someone else wants to share a different approach.

Comment: if you have the UUID why not look up the disk in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`? Read the link then check if that disk is mounted.

Comment: @Centimane Because only main LV extended partition is listed there, and this does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `blkid -U` to get the block device from the UUID e.g.

```
blkid -U "897da7b7-edb1-4a6c-94e0-0a6175c89273"
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv0
```

and then use `lsblk` or `findmnt` to get the mount point - for example

```
lsblk -no MOUNTPOINT "$(blkid -U "897da7b7-edb1-4a6c-94e0-0a6175c89273")"
/storage/mythtv

findmnt "$(blkid -U "897da7b7-edb1-4a6c-94e0-0a6175c89273")"
TARGET          SOURCE              FSTYPE OPTIONS
/storage/mythtv /dev/mapper/vg0-lv0 xfs    rw,noatime,attr2,delaylog,allocsize=5
/var/lib/mythtv /dev/mapper/vg0-lv0 xfs    rw,noatime,attr2,delaylog,allocsize=5
```

(the second entry is a bind mount in this case).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using device without `lsblk` and `findmnt`(for example: Oracle Enterprise Linux 5), and you can't access the internet in that device, use `cat /etc/fstab` or `cat /proc/mounts`.

You can't see the UUID, but you can see logical volume and where it's mounted.