# Find out disks, which do not have any partitions/LVs mounted

Tags: scripting, fedora, lvm, lsblk

Contrary to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322802/179000) question, I would like to know which (physical) disks currently do not have any partitions or LVs mounted.  This is for a script, which shall return disks where none of their partitions or LVs are currently mounted in the system.

Is there a (fairly) simple way to find that out using command-line tools (ideally using a mix of bash built-ins, grep, lsblk and sed, but avoiding "`awk`ward" programming or highly specialized 3rd party programs if possible).

**EDIT (for clarification):**

I am looking for a way to get "/dev/sdc" and/or "/dev/sdd" if not a single partition (e.g. none of /dev/sdc{1,2,3,4}) or LV (e.g. /dev/mapper/some_VG_name-LV_name) is currently mounted on the system.  If even a single partition or LV is mounted, the disk shall not be returned.

Comment: `lsblk` command?

Comment: Yes.  `lsblk` is possibly one good source (as mentioned in the question itself).  However, finding the right switches to return precisely what I am looking for is currently not so successful.  Using `lsblk --list --paths` will detach any LVs from their drives as they are listed as `/dev/mapper/...` instead of `/dev/sd?/...`  Keep in mind that a script shall parse it.  Not a human eye. ;-)

Comment: You are looking for attached devices that are NOT mounted. Can you change the headline of your question?

Comment: Ok.  Done.  Thanks for making me aware.  Though it would be fine either way.  If I go through disks to find partitions or logical volumes attached, I could just revert the results to get what I need.  In essence I would need to get the disks, however, and not all unmounted partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, which works for me:

```bsh
aAllDisks=($(/usr/bin/lsblk --nodeps --noheadings --output NAME --paths))
aFreeDisks=()
for sDisk in "${aAllDisks[@]}"; do
    sMounts="$(/usr/bin/lsblk --noheadings --output MOUNTPOINT "${sDisk}" | grep -vE "^$")"
    if [ "${sMounts}" == "" ]; then
        aFreeDisks+=("${sDisk}")
    fi
done
echo "${aFreeDisks[@]}"
```

This will first get all installed physical disks and then loop through them.  If a disk does not have any mounts, it will be gathered for later use.  In the above example, I simply echo it out.

Comment: It should be noted that despite its name and despite it not being mentioned anywhere in its manual page, `lsblk` will also list lvm2 volumes, luks partitions and so on.